Looking for Spanish term designating specific part of lamp
Good morning,
Not exactly a question about Spanish language, but I can't think of better place to ask.
I would appreciate if you could give the Spanish term for the metallic part of table lamp where glass bowl sits. It is depicted below (in English I would probably use words like socket or vase cap). I need to buy one, but I have no idea how to name the thing.



No creo que exista un término específico para eso. Además, es la parte más importante y menos universal que puede tener una lámpara, por lo que es más fácil conseguir una lámpara nueva que averiguar por esa única parte...

Es algo así como pedir el asiento propiamente dicho de un asiento teniendo sólo el respaldo.

I agree with tac, I haven't found a specific name for that part. Where you put the bulb is known as portalamparas but the union between that and the rest of the lamp got no name as far as I know.

I believe I have found this term, please see my comment to the accepted answer (it seems to be «portaglobos»). I am not sure if this term is in use in all the Spanish-speaking countries, though.

https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/portaglobos le pifiaste y por lejos

@tac Well, I do not know. This seems to be it: https://www.fabricatulampara.com/1550-portatulipas-portaglobos-y-tapas.

Or, it is more accurate to say, this is exactly it.

Portalámparas


m. Parte metálica destinada a recibir el casquillo de la bombilla y asegurar la conexión de la lámpara con el circuito eléctrico.


RAE

I think that OP is asking about a specific part of the lamp base (pie de lámpara), the one "where the glass bowl sits" (el anillo donde se engancha el globo de cristal)

Ah! La rosca o en todo caso "la base de la rosca"

@Danielillo Thank you very much! The perfect match for the term I need seems to be «portaglobos»! Lots of them are offered at, for example,  https://www.fabricatulampara.com/1550-portatulipas-portaglobos-y-tapas.
Still, it was your suggestion that made it possible for me to find this site.
